# Field has Leading Zeros, gets removed after a 'UNION ALL'

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables that have the same field (data type of Nvarchar(12),NUll).
this allows the field to allow/show the leading zeros.

After I did a Union ALL, the second table has the leading Zeros removed.
I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Thank you all for your help!

```
Select Account  , name
From (
select Account
   , name
from table A
Union All
select Account
   , name
from table B)
```

This is what I get:

```
 Account name
 0002    Name1
 0003    Name3
 0004    Name4
 5       Name5
 8       Name6
```

This is what I want

```
  Account name
 0002    Name1
 0003    Name3
 0004    Name4
 0005    Name5
 0008    Name6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JNevill said, the data types of each column are determined by the first SELECT statement. In your question you state that each table has the same data type, which is NVARCHAR(12).

In [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), they say that

> When data types differ, the resulting data type is determined based on the rules for data type precedence. When the types are the same but differ in precision, scale, or length, the result is based on the same rules for combining expressions.

My guess is that the types are based on the rules for combining expressions. If you look at [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server 2017, NVARCHAR types are in the last types, and numeric ones are higher in priority. So I guess that having "0001" as value is somewhat converted to numeric in SQL Server.
Casting values as NVARCHAR in your first SELECT of your UNION ALL (as JNevill suggested) will fix your problem.

Just did a quick test and I can't reproduce your problem with NVARCHAR types. Even when specifying NULLs in my column. The only way I can have it is if one of my columns is numeric. So I guess you should check the datatypes of your tables in your UNION ALL. Or give a sample code to reproduce your problem.

```
    Create Table test1 (Id int not null identity(1,1), name nvarchar(12) null)
    Create Table test2 (Id int not null identity(1,1), name nvarchar(12) null)

    insert into test1 (name) values ('0001')
    insert into test1 (name) values ('0002')
    insert into test1 (name) values ('3')
    insert into test1 (name) values (NULL)

    insert into test2 (name) values ('0004')
    insert into test2 (name) values ('0005')
    insert into test2 (name) values ('6')

    SELECT name from test1 union all select name from test2
```

Comment: Hi Danielle, Thank you for the links. I did ad in the cast as mentioned by you and Jnevill. Unfortunately, that did not work. Both tables do show the leading zeros, but get removed after i do a union. I also switch the tables around to see if that would help, but that didn't help.

Comment: I queried all accounts from my second table. It looks like some records on the table have leading zeros and other records do not. Do you think this could be the cause of my issue?

Comment: well when I tried, I had some numbers with leading zeros and others without, and it worked well. So I don't think it will cause any problem. Maybe you can provide a sample of data to reproduce the bug? What version of SQL are you using? Are you using #temp tables?

Comment: I added the following to the table: Right('0000000000'+cast(Account) as varchar(12)),10). This fixed the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In a union the data types of each column are determined by the first SELECT statement. I assume that you `Account` is numeric in the `Table A`. To fix, CAST as varchar:

```
Select Account , name From ( select CAST(Account as varchar(20)) as Account , name from table A Union All select Account , name from table B)
```